# Equivalent of getContainer() in GMaps API 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there an equivalent of the function map.getContainer() in API V3?

```
var map;
var mapContainer = $(map.getContainer());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/ref_getdiv.asp you can use

```
var map;
var mapContainer = map.getDiv();
```

to get the parent div.